# How do I change my classes private attribute value?

Tags: c++

If I use a setter, it should then change my private classes attribute's value right? However that's not the case, it's just giving me the default value of the private attribute when I use the setter. I am finding the distance travelled value with a getter.

## Player.h

```
#pragma once

class Player
{
public:

    void setForestDistanceTravelled(int amount);
    int getForestDistanceTravelled();
private:
    unsigned short int forestDistanceTravelled = 0;
};
```

## Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

void Player::setForestDistanceTravelled(int amount)
{
    forestDistanceTravelled += amount;
}
int Player::getForestDistanceTravelled()
{
    return forestDistanceTravelled;
}
```

## forest.cpp

```
void welcomeToForest()
{
    Forest forest;
    Player player;
    std::string userInput;
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Your current distance is: " << player.getForestDistanceTravelled();
    std::cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput == "1")
    {
        unsigned short int playerDist = 0;
        system("cls");
        playerDist = forestDistanceRand();
        player.setForestDistanceTravelled(playerDist);
        welcomeToForest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: With each recursive call to `welcomeToForest` you get a completely new `player`, which naturally has `forestDistanceTravelled` equal to `0`. Recurency is a wrong solution here.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that makes sense. But how do I get the player object everywhere? a global player object cause i really wouldnt like that... I'm guessing a completely different approach to getters and setters..?

Comment: Your getter and setter is fine, but you need to change recurrency into a loop (technically, you can make it work in recurrent way, but there's no reason to do that).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I'm not only going to use the player object in that function, I'm going to be using it in many functions

Comment: @Mustafizr Are you sure that you want += in the setter instead of =? Generally "set" methods assign to the value, not add some amount to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yksisarvinen states in the comments, the problem lays in new instances of the `Player` object spawning again and again with each recursion of `welcomeToForest()`.

You just want to isolate the recursive bit of that function into its own function, that accepts the `Player` object as an outside parameter.

Something like below should work, whilst preserving the recursive logic of the program:

```
void recursiveBit(Player& player_)
{
    std::string userInput;
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Your current distance is: " 
              << player.getForestDistanceTravelled();
    std::cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput == "1")
    {
        unsigned short int playerDist = 0;
        system("cls");
        playerDist = forestDistanceRand();
        player_.setForestDistanceTravelled(playerDist);
        recursiveBit(player_);
    }
}

void welcomeToForest()
{
    Forest forest;
    Player player;
    recursiveBit(player);
}
```

Comment: does that mean i have to always put the player object in my functions arguments to use them? that seems quite inefficient since my program is based around the player

Comment: @Mustafizr yes, if you need recursions in all your functions and need to use `Player` function members like `setForestDistanceTravelled()`. It is not computationally inefficient to pass arguments to functions by the way, that's what functions are for. You could make `setForestDistanceTravelled()` an external function with respect to the `Player` class, but then you'd need to specify which player you want to travel in the forest, by passing its instance as a parameter to that function, and you'd be back to square 1.